# Mount USB drive with write permissions for everyone or specific user

Tags: mount, permissions, filesystem, usb-drive, fstab

I know there are similar questions but I get some specific problem I can't overcome.

I have:

- HDD split into two partitions. `/dev/sdb1` and `/dev/sdb2`.  `sdb1` is NTFS and I don't need it. I need `sdb2` which is fat32.
- Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS (server)

I want:

Ultimately I need a perma-mount `/dev/sdb2` to `/home/storage` with access right (rw) for the user `media`.

Problems I'm facing:

Using manual mount from command line.

If I just use

```
server# sudo mount /dev/sdb2 /home/storage
```

It mounts but the `/home/storage` receives root as owner and group and doesn't allow `media` user to write there.

If I use `mount` command without `sudo` as the user `media` - i'm not allowed. Says only root can use mount.

If I use `mount` with options: `server# sudo mount /dev/sdb2 /home/storage -o umask=000` I get what I need. A bit overdone of course, since the storage folder becomes writable for everyone. **BUT - that is manually mounted - now i need it to remount on every reboot.**

Remounting on reboot - using `fstab`**

So I thought I'll be fine if I use `fstab` to mount this partition (`/dev/sdb2`) every time i reboot. The `fstab` line I added:

```
UUID=8C52-C1CD /home/storage auto   user,umask=000,utf8,noauto  0   0
```

Got uuid with `blkid`. The fs type `auto` I changed a few times... I tried `vfat` too, but always on the reboot Ubuntu stops when processing fstab (I think) with the message (took from the log):

```
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
/dev/sda5: clean, 120559/10969088 files, 19960144/43861504 blocks
mount: unknown filesystem type 'static'
mountall: mount /etc/fstab: [772] terminated with status 32
mountall: Filesystem could not be mounted: /etc/fstab:
Skipping /etc/fstab: at user request
```

And also - `sudo mount -a` never really does anything.

What am I doing wrong? I do suspect I messed up something:)

It seems `fstab` should hold only mounts for static drives, not any sort of usb stuff. I'm puzzled how then this works with all the people posting on the net their success stories...

However... if this is not possible - I would like to know how to remount my USB after every reboot... if not with `fstab` - then how? :)

Comment: I think you should post all of fstab for review, and not just one line. As for the right permissions, run `id media` and use `uid=` and `gid=` and `umask=027`options.

Comment: Is there some reason you need to use FAT ? If not, I would back up the data and use a linux native file system. You can then set ownership and permissions.

Comment: @mikewhatever  thanks but it's working strangely actually... well..not really:)

Comment: @bodhi.zazen did more reading... seams like on ubuntu 12 fstab should have only mounts for static drives. not any usb...

Comment: run the `id` cmd and use the mount options of your id and group thus allowing your `$USER` account to read/write the drive. use `-o uid=[UID],gid=[GID]` the UID and GID can be gathered from the running the `id` cmd.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Your problem seems to be about the permissions you have set. FAT / FAT32 formatted drives don't support file permissions. The permissions for everything are determined by how the drive is mounted. When you set the permission open it worked when you

```
server# sudo mount /dev/sdb2 /home/storage -o umask=000
```

As for it not auto mounting on reboot

```
UUID=8C52-C1CD /home/storage auto user,umask=000,utf8, -->noauto<-- 0 0
```

The "noauto" makes this NOT automatically mount when the system starts and parses the /etc/fstab file.  Remove that option and it will mount on startup. You can set the permissions on the mount point once it's mounted with `chmod` or specify them in /etc/fstab.

If you need the media user to access it, you can set the permissions to 764, and add them to the security group. Root always has access to everything.

see http://www.linux.org/threads/file-permissions-chmod.4094/ for some examples of propper file permissions

On a side note, bodhi.zazen made a good point
Is there some reason you need to use FAT ? If not, I would back up the data and use a linux native file system. You can then set ownership and permissions.

Comment: `-o umask=000` is it!! Thank you!

Comment: I already have tried many ways on internet to create a writable unit... '-o umask=000' this help. Very thanks

Comment: only answer that worked for me

Answer (score 5):

**Note**: as mentioned in the comments below, be careful using 0777 permissions: it means anyone, or any script, on the machine can write to the drive. With that caveat in mind, this can sometimes be a useful fix in a pinch:

You can also run

```
sudo chmod 0777 /home/storage
```

Since FAT drives don't have permissions, linux applies the permission of the mount point to the entire drive.

Comment: Never apply R+W+X permissions for every user.. This would allow anyone or anything to access,execute,delete,modify storage and its contents....

Comment: On most operating systems, USB drives are mounted so any user can modify the contents. If you are a server admin in a situation where this could be an issue, I wouldn't have to tell you what 0777 means.

Comment: Drives are never mounted by default to allow all users, This is why they have groups and permissions. Either way its always safer to show a better security mod as people will simply copy and paste without knowing better

Comment: Works like a charm. @Angry84 Anyone, like a malicious script?

Comment: while i would not use 0777, the idea went into the correct direction and is therefore a helpful answer for some.

Comment: @Angry84 is right that this at least deserves a warning, which I have added to the top of my answer. I still think this is a helpful answer in some circumstances given that it's easier than mounting/unmounting so can be helpful in a pinch, as it was for me at the time of writing.

Comment: This doesn't work for vfat. The drive and all files are owned by root and have 755 permissions which cannot be changed even with sudo.

Answer (score 4):

Unless overridden by mount options GID= or UID= the owner and permissions of
the mount point upon mounting become those of the filesystem tree being
mounted.

So if /dev/sdb1 contains an ext4 filesystem (say a backup) owned by user
then user will become the owner of the mount point upon successful mount.

Starting off we have an empty folder 'backup' to serve as the mount point,
and is owned by root.

```
# ls -alR /mnt
/mnt/:
drwxr-x---  5 root root 4096 May 30 20:59 ./
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Dec  5  2015 ../
drwx------  2 root root 4096 Jan  1 07:45 backup/

/mnt/backup:
drwx------  2 root root 4096 Jan  1 07:45 .
drwxr-x---  5 root root 4096 May 30 20:59 ..
```

now we mount /dev/sdb1 (read-only)

```
# mount -o ro /dev/sdb1 /mnt/backup
```

and lets see...

```
# ls -alR
/mnt/:
drwxr-x---  5 root root 4096 May 30 20:59 ./
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Dec  5  2015 ../
drwx------  2 user user 4096 Jan  1 07:45 backup/

/mnt/backup:
drwx------  2 user user 4096 Jan  1 07:45 .
drwxr-x---  5 root root 4096 May 30 20:59 ..
-rw-------  1 user user 252076021760 Jun  9 21:11 backup.tar
```

Now if you've got an empty drive and you want to mount it for 'user' as an
extension of 'user's disk space, mount the drive as root, chown the root of
the mount to 'user' and unmount.

The next time the filesystem is mounted (by root or anyone as per fstab) the
owner of the mount will be 'user'.

Answer (score 0):

Without mounting to /home/storage (very fast):

```
$ pcmanfm  
$ df -h  
... /dev/sdb2 ...  
$ chown -hR user:group /media/user/a13*
```

Answer (score -1):

If you do have external storage device connected to your Linux box with NTFS, make sure that the filesystem is clean.

Before you mount the storage to your Linux box:

1. Run the below command

   ```
   ntfsfix /dev/storagedevice ( like sdb1 or sdc1 )
   ```
2. Reboot your Linux box
3. Mount the external storage by running the command:

   ```
   mount -o rw /dev/storagedevice /media/
   ```

   or

   ```
   mount -o rw /dev/storagedevice /mnt/
   ```

   or mount the storagedevice via GUI.

Comment: What is your reasoning behind each of these steps?