# Auto-mount usb drive on chromebook to use with dropbox

Tags: usb, mount, encryption, dropbox, chromebook

I have replaced Chrome OS on my Acer C720 with Ubuntu 14.04, so far I'm quite happy besides the limited local storage capasity. To remedy this I have bought a 32 GB USB Drive (SanDisk Cruzer Fit) and are planning to use this as an extension to the internal harddrive, preferably auto-mounted on startup with a fixed path so that I can put use It for dropbox. But I do not want to compromise security, so I would need the USB Drive to be encrypted like my home folder.

Is It possible to auto-mount the USB Drive with a fixed path so I can have a constant dropbox setup on It (I sadly need a local copy of my dropbox)? Is It possible to do something smart security wise so that I don't compromise my data on the usb drive If my laptop get stolen.

I know there is possible to upgrade the internal ssd and that this would solve all my problems, but It's to expensive for the moment and I would really like to put the USB Drive into some good use If possible.

Thanks in advanced for feedback on this post.

Comment: This question has info on mounting a USB drive manually: http://askubuntu.com/questions/251206/mount-usb-drive-with-write-permissions-for-everyone-or-specific-user