# How to format a read-only USB-Lubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, usb, lubuntu, lts, read-only

I was trying all the commands that appears in all posts about this topic but I can't format my USB with a partition of 16mb that is read-only.

Is there another form for do it?

Thanks

Comment: You cannot format a read-only drive.  You have to mount it Read-write in order to perform a write operation.

Comment: How can I do it?

Comment: Check out http://askubuntu.com/q/251206/527350

Comment: mount: cannot remount /dev/sdc read-write, is write-protected

Comment: @antonio8909 This is the error I always see when there is some sort of hardware switch on the drive preventing writing.

Comment: @NonnyMoose So it's impossible?

Comment: @antonio8909 Possibly, if it is broken or hardware-locked.

Comment: I think it isn't broken @NonnyMoose I went to a meeting today and they gave me a 8gb usb drive with a 16mb partition with a useless pdf inside that I don't need but I think I will need to deal with it. Thanks anyway! ^^