# HDD requires superuser permissions to write

Tags: permissions, mount, hard-drive

After installing Ubuntu18.04 on SSD, an empty internal hard-drive has the following permissions and can't be written on without sudo.

> drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 32768 Jan  1  1970 Storage

The HDD had Win10 installed on before, but was formatted clean prior to Ubuntu18.04 install.

I've used Ubuntu16.04 for a couple years with Win10 dualboot and never had a problem with the HDD permissions.
Tried multiple solutions and couldn't get it to work yet.

`sudo chown $USER:$USER /mnt/Storage` (also with -R) returns the following:

> chown: changing ownership of '/mnt/Storage': Operation not permitted

Unplugging and plugging again didnt work as well.

fstab relevant info:

> LABEL=Storage /mnt/Storage auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 2

Comment: what file system are you using?  how did you format it? since it's empty, can you try to format it again?

Comment: @Nmath Formatted using `gnome-disks ` gui, file system as FAT(For use with all systems and devices). I sure can try formatting it again, what changes would you suggest

Comment: @Nmath Tried format as FAT got same issue. Changed format to Ext4 and chown permissions changed successfully. Tried again as FAT, same issue again.

Comment: I am opening it as sudo, and yes I am formatting the drive and not just deleting and creating new partitions (right click the only partition there is and selecting format partition). Although I also tried deleting and creating new partitions

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/251206/mount-usb-drive-with-write-permissions-for-everyone-or-specific-user

Comment: Since its an empty drive I would create a new partition table. Then a partition inside with the mount in /media/user/newDrive.  With the mounting done by fstab in a user it shuld be fine.